# While running the design using command line with MPI for Intel Inspector in linux shell it shows error

Tags: linux, operating-system, mpi, intel-inspector

While running the design using command line with MPI for Intel Inspector in Linux shell it shows error of

Error: Unsupported OS version .
Linux OS should be RedHat 7 or 8/CentOS 7 or 8
Exiting.

Can anyone tell me what should I do for this or what changes should be made in which file?

Comment: What operating system are you running on?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the operating system on which you're running Intel Inspector is not supported by Intel Inspector. Could you please provide which OS are you using? Or as the error suggested, please use any of the given OS i.e. *Linux OS should be RedHat 7 or 8/CentOS 7 or 8*